# How do I make a script to run another program after a file is created in a specific folder?

Tags: monitor, rclone

How do I make a script to run another program after a file is created in a specific folder? Could be Windows or Linux. To be specific, I want to use rclone to move file to remote folder right after it is created. The program itself doesnt have built-in monitoring function

Answer (score 0):

> Could be Windows or Linux.

Linux: It's easy with [`inotifywait`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/inotifywait.1.html).

```
cd "a specific folder"
inotifywait -me close_write --format %f . | while read file
do  rclone move "$file" …
done
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work with the Ubuntu Linux app from the Windows Store for files on mounted Windows filesystems.